# Turbolinks: How to manually end a javascript session in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

In my Rails App, I have a javascript Timer in one page. When using turbolinks, the Timer object would persist between pages.

So, when user starts the timer in the `timer.html.erb` and go to another page and change back, the timer is still running(persistes), instead of starting again.

I'd like to show you my example. But where to put it? JS fiddle? Heroku?

Notice:
I've tried that, if I turn the turbo links off, everthing would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing Turbolinks, I would use their [events](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events) to reload the timer each time the page loads:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var timer = function() {
    //timer init
};

$(document).ready(timer);
$(document).on('page:load', timer);
```

Comment: But by calling timer twice, We'll start the clock twice. How to solve this?

Comment: Have you tested it? The `document.ready` initiates the timer when you load the timer & `page:load` refreshes. You could just get rid of the `$(document).ready` call if it's calling twice

Comment: Let me ask another question. `$(document).on('page:load', timer);` actually fire the function every time user enter a page, no matter what page he is in. Can I make this statement page-specific?(e.g. When he is in a certain page.)

Comment: Sure - you can just use a condition inside the `timer` function. The `page:load` is just a [turbolinks event](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events), meaning you should put any logic into the function you're looking to call

Comment: Then I would put a <div id="js-customIdentifier">, and use js to check for its existence for cutsomFunction. Is this a good practice? Or what is a good practice?

Comment: Yep, that's what I would do to begin with -- you might be able to reference the location or something, but bottom line is you need some sort of identifying element (either in URL or in HTML)